# RecyclerView with variable size lists

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing a project for an Android Course and I am trying to apply RecyclerView. The project is about a quizz, where I have a number of questions, each with different options. I have already a "working" version at github, but it is implemented with a recyclerView inside another recyclerView, for questions and answerOptions, respectivelly. I want to change this, since it seems "weird".

I could easily create a layout for each question, but I want to make it a little more "general". I imagine I could have, for example, 100 options in each question. In this case, I would want to repeat the same pattern for each AnswerOption. I already tried to add some views dynamically, but I didn't learn so much about this, so I am a little lost. Please ask me anything that can be missing to help you helping me.

Thank you in advance!

The full "working" project is here. I am trying to avoid using a recyclerView inside another, but still "recycle" somehow.
https://github.com/Rheneni/QuizzApp_Udacity

How I am starting the activity:

```
static final int QUESTIONS_NUMBER = 1;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mSolutions = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> mOptionTypes = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> mQuestionNumOptions = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<Question> mQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
private QuestionAdapter mAdapter;
private int questionsCorrect = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fillLists();
    for(int i = 0; i < QUESTIONS_NUMBER; i++) {
        mQuestions.add(new Question(this, i+1, mOptionTypes.get(i), mQuestionNumOptions.get(i)));
    }

    setupRecycler();
}

private void setupRecycler() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_layout_recycler);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(QuestionLayoutActivity.this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new QuestionAdapter(this, mQuestions);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
}
```

My Adapter right now (not working) and giving this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int QUESTION_VIEW  = 1;
private static final int RADIO_OPTION_VIEW = 2;
private static final int CHECKBOX_OPTION_VIEW = 3;
private static final int FREE_ANSWER = 4;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Question> mQuestions;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public QuestionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questions) {
    mContext = context;
    if (questions != null)
        mQuestions = new ArrayList<>(questions);
    else mQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView questionNumber;
    public TextView questionText;
    public TextView radioOptionText;
    public RadioButton radioOption;
    public TextView checkBoxOptionText;
    public CheckBox checkBoxOption;
    public TextView freeText;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        questionNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_number);
        questionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);

        radioOption = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_radio);
        radioOptionText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);

        checkBoxOption = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_checkbox);
        checkBoxOptionText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_text);

        freeText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.option_free);
    }

    public void bindRadioViewList(int pos){
        Log.d("tag", "pos:" + pos);
        Question question = mQuestions.get(pos);

        String message = question.getQuestionName();
        Log.d("tag", message);
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionName());
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionText());
        Log.d("tag", "" + question.getOptionsNumber());


        final String text = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getOptionText();
        final boolean isChecked = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getIsChecked();
        //questionNumber.setText(question.getQuestionName());
        //questionText.setText(question.getQuestionText());

        radioOptionText.setText(text);
        radioOption.setSelected(isChecked);
    }

    public void bindCheckBoxViewList(int pos){
        Log.d("tag", "pos:" + pos);
        Question question = mQuestions.get(pos);

        String message = question.getQuestionName();
        Log.d("tag", message);
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionName());
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionText());
        Log.d("tag", "" + question.getOptionsNumber());

        final String text = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getOptionText();
        final boolean isChecked = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getIsChecked();
        //questionNumber.setText(question.getQuestionName());
        //questionText.setText(question.getQuestionText());

        checkBoxOptionText.setText(text);
        checkBoxOption.setSelected(isChecked);
    }

    public void bindQuestionRadioViewList(int pos){
        Log.d("tag", "pos:" + pos);
        Question question = mQuestions.get(pos);

        String message = question.getQuestionName();
        Log.d("tag", message);
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionName());
        Log.d("tag", question.getQuestionText());
        Log.d("tag", "" + question.getOptionsNumber());

        final String text = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getOptionText();
        final boolean isChecked = question.getAnswerOptions().get(0).getIsChecked();
        questionNumber.setText(question.getQuestionName());
        questionText.setText(question.getQuestionText());

        radioOptionText.setText(text);
        radioOption.setSelected(isChecked);
    }
}

private class QuestionViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    public QuestionViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class RadioViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    public RadioViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class CheckBoxViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    public CheckBoxViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    if(viewType == RADIO_OPTION_VIEW) {
        //v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_radio_option, parent, false);
        //RadioViewHolder vh = new RadioViewHolder(v);
        LinearLayout questionLayout = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question, parent, false);
        if(questionLayout.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup)questionLayout.getParent()).removeView(questionLayout);
        }
        LinearLayout optionsLayout = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_radio_option, parent, false);
        if(optionsLayout.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup)optionsLayout.getParent()).removeView(optionsLayout);
        }
        parent.addView(questionLayout);
        parent.addView(optionsLayout);
        View view = parent;
        QuestionViewHolder vh = new QuestionViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }
    else if(viewType == CHECKBOX_OPTION_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_checkbox_option, parent, false);
        CheckBoxViewHolder vh = new CheckBoxViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    else {
        Log.d("tag", "viewType not found");
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_radio_option, parent, false);
        RadioViewHolder vh = new RadioViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        if (holder instanceof QuestionViewHolder) {
            //RadioViewHolder vh = (RadioViewHolder) holder;
            //vh.bindRadioViewList(position);
            QuestionViewHolder vh = (QuestionViewHolder)holder;
            vh.bindQuestionRadioViewList(position);
        }
        else if(holder instanceof CheckBoxViewHolder) {
            CheckBoxViewHolder vh = (CheckBoxViewHolder) holder;
            vh.bindCheckBoxViewList(position);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("tag", "bind Done");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int count = 0;
    if(mQuestions != null){
        count = mQuestions.size();
    }
    return count;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to use RecyclerView expand/collapse items

Comment: Rather than scrolling down questions why not ask one question in a page? so that a options can have a recycler view in pageviewer layout

Comment: @sanemars I will check that out

Comment: @Satya The idea would be to allow to "scroll" and then I would add a "next" button to allow to go directly to the next questions. Or even a "previous".